# Fork currect Drupal installation

Tags: 7, installation

Is it possible to fork current Drupal installation for experiments and have two versions of Drupal with one installation of Apache, PHP and MySQL on Ubuntu?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes; See the handbook page on drupal.org: [Installing virtual hosts for Drupal sites and subsites](http://drupal.org/node/111238).

Comment: @kiamlaluno you are doing pedantic changes in my answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can install two instances of Drupal in different sub-directories of the Server root directory; when you install them, you need to use different databases, or a different prefix for the tables used from each Drupal installation.

Doing so, I was able to have an instance of Drupal 5, two instances of Drupal 6, and two instances of Drupal 7 in my test computer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you want to do.  You could obviously just have two folders with the two different versions in it, and give the database tables different prefixes on install.